# Can application generate radio signal

Tags: android

I want to know is there a possiblity to generate radio signal from my mobile.
I have been thinking of Andriod Applications which should do this functionality 
Like a remote for Air Condition.()

If Yes, give me link?
if No, what are the limitations?

Comment: This might be of some help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142853/mobile-phone-can-it-programatically-broadcast-at-a-radio-frequency